# Can we have one vtable shared my multiple classes

Tags: c++, vtable

Is it possible in C++ to have one vtable shared by multiple classes?
As per my understanding if a class is having a virtual function then it will generate a vtable.So every class should have its own vtable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorphism could be implemented several ways. And vtables could also be implemented several ways. But usually in following case

```
class A {
    virtual foo(){}
}

class B : public A {
    virtual foo(){}
}

class C : public B {
    void fooNonVirtual(){};
}
```

classes `B` and `C` should have the same vtable.

Example:

```
A *a = new A;
B *b = new B;
C *c = new C;
a->foo(); // A::foo is called
((A*)b)->foo(); // B::foo is called
((A*)c)->foo(); // B::foo is called
```

`foo` for `a` and `b` calls different methods because A and B has different vtables. For `b` and `c` the same method is called. So compiler could make some optimization and create only one vtable for B and C classes.

`fooNonVirtual` is not virtual and do not require vtables at all.

Comment: so it means if Base and derived classes share same set of virtual funcitons then compiler may force them to use same vtable?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I ve updated answer (added `void fooNonVirtual(){};`) to make it more obvious.

Comment: But I feel class A and B should have same vtable and not B and C

Comment: `A` and `B` can't possibly have the same vtable because their entries for the `foo` function would need to point to two different places. A single slot in a single table can't have two different values, so there must be two separate tables for `A` and `B`. `C`, on the other hand, inherits its `foo` implementation from `B`, so it's conceivable that `B` and `C` could share a single vtable. That depends on *what else* the compiler implementation chooses to store in vtables.

Comment: Avt, is there some code you could execute with those definitions of `A`, `B` and `C` that would *demonstrate* which of them have the same vtables?

Comment: @RobKennedy, It is not easy to explain vtables and polymorphism in few words.

Comment: That's fine. I'm not concerned with the number of words. The code you added doesn't really demonstrate vtables being shared, though.

Comment: @RobKennedy I do my best. Feel free to edit my answer if you can improve it.

Comment: I can't imagine a compiler which didn't put a pointer to RTTI information in the `vtable`.  Which would mean that two different most derived classes cannot ever share the same `vtable`.  On the other hand, in an object of type `C`, there will be only one `vptr`, pointing to a vtable which is shared between `C` and its subobjects; perhaps this is what was meant.

Comment: As I know RTTI could be disabled to decrease size and increase performance.

Answer (score 6):

Vtables are an implementation detail. C++ doesn't have vtables, it has virtual functions. Vtables just happen to be the most common (if not only) implementation, and the details differ.

What is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Someone asked me in interview if we can have vtable shared by multiple classes and I said no..so just curious what is actual answer.

Comment: The correct answer is it's theoretically possible, only because it's an implementation detail.

Comment: I hate this kind of interview question. The factual answer is that you, as the programmer, cannot force this, but the compiler is free to share identical vtables. (But if the compiler makes a pointer to the dynamic type info part of the vtable, as those I know do, then that won't happen.)

Comment: @SebastianRedl Maybe the job involves implementing a compiler, a debugger or some other sort of low-level hackery - then this might be a good question

Comment: @anatolyg Granted, if intense understanding of C++ internals is a job requirement, then it's a reasonable question. In all other situations, it signifies what I think is a problematic mindset - either a love of trivia or lack of focus on the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
typedef some::Class AnotherClass;
```

and then these classes would share.

Also, inheritance could - at least theoretically - result in the sharing of vtables.

Comment: In fact, this would not even create a second class so there is still only one class. This class only shares its vtable with itself. (typedef only creates an alias to a name, not a new type. So some::Class and AnotherClass still refer to the same type.)

Comment: @anderas Rest assured that I knew that when I wrote this. You can support the opinion (!) that another name establishes another class, at least in some logical way. And, finally, trick questions - targeting implementation details - deserve trick answers.

Answer (score 0):

A vtable is basically a table of virtual functions, so if the two classes have the same virtual functions, it seems pretty straightforward to share the vtable.

```
struct Class1
{
    virtual void func() { /* whatever */ }
};

struct Class2 // can share the vtable with Class1
{
    void nonvirtual_func() { /* whatever */ }
};
```

However, vtable may also contain other info (e.g. the stuff returned by `typeid`) - in this case, sharing the vtable is impossible. Some compilers have an option to disable RTTI and `typeid` - so that setting may affect the answer to the question.

Comment: I am little confused here , as mentioned by @Avt class A and class B share same set of virtual functions, so they can also share same vtable?

Comment: I think they cannot, because the functions really are not the same (they have the same implementation, but their addresses must be different), but I am not sure about this

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what is being asked.  A single class may
have many different `vtable`, depending on how it is used.  And
the compiler will merge the vtables of several classes in
a hierarchy.  For example:

```
struct VB { virtual ~VB() = default; };
struct L : virtual VB {};
struct R : virtual VB {};
struct D : L, R {};
```

In this scenario, the vtable for `VB` will be different 
depending on whether you instantiate an `L`, and `R` or a `D`.
On the other hand, in an object with the most derived type `D`,
both `D` and the base class `L` will probably share the same
`vtable`.